# Can't overload operator (CS0563)

Tags: c#, .net

I created class Either3 so I want to overload + operator. I've got CS0563 on overloaded operator.

Here's Either3:

```cs
using System;

namespace NDP.MathUtils.Utils
{
    public class Either3<T1, T2, T3>
    {
        private readonly T1 first;
        private readonly T2 second;
        private readonly T3 third;
        private readonly byte which;

        public Either3(T1 first)
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.which = 1;
        }

        public Either3(T2 second)
        {
            this.second = second;
            this.which = 2;
        }

        public Either3(T3 third)
        {
            this.third = third;
            this.which = 3;
        }

        public T Match<T>(Func<T1, T> firstFunc, Func<T2, T> secondFunc, Func<T3, T> thirdFunc)
        {
            if (firstFunc == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstFunc));
            }

            if (secondFunc == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secondFunc));
            }

            if (thirdFunc == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(thirdFunc));
            }

            switch (which)
            {
                case 1: return firstFunc(this.first);
                case 2: return secondFunc(this.second);
                case 3: return thirdFunc(this.third);
                default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        public T1 FirstOrDefault() => this.Match(f => f, s => default(T1), t => default(T1));

        public T2 SecondOrDefault() => this.Match(f => default(T2), s => s, t => default(T2));

        public T3 ThirdOrDefault() => this.Match(f => default(T3), s => default(T3), t => t);

        public static implicit operator Either3<T1, T2, T3>(T1 first) => new Either3<T1, T2, T3>(first);

        public static implicit operator Either3<T1, T2, T3>(T2 second) => new Either3<T1, T2, T3>(second);

        public static implicit operator Either3<T1, T2, T3>(T3 third) => new Either3<T1, T2, T3>(third);
    }
}
```

And overloaded method, which has an CS0563:

```cs
public static Either3<int, CommonFraction, float> operator +(Either3<int, CommonFraction, float> a, Either3<int, CommonFraction, float> b)
        {
            byte type = 0;
            object result = a.Match<object>(
                delegate (int ai) {
                    return b.Match<object>(
                        (int bi)            => { type = 1; return ai + bi; },
                        (CommonFraction bc) => { type = 2; return ai + bc; },
                        (float bf)          => { type = 3; return ai + bf; }
                    );
                },

                delegate (CommonFraction ac) {
                    return b.Match<object>(
                        (int bi)            => { type = 2; return ac + bi; },
                        (CommonFraction bc) => { type = 2; return ac + bc; },
                        (float bf)          => { type = 3; return ac.GetRealValue() + bf; }
                    );
                },

                delegate (float af){
                    return b.Match<object>(
                        (int bi)            => { type = 3; return af + bi; },
                        (CommonFraction bc) => { type = 3; return af + bc.GetRealValue(); },
                        (float bf)          => { type = 3; return af + bf; }
                    );
                }
            );

            switch (type)
            {
                case 1: return new Either3<int, CommonFraction, float>((int)result);
                case 2: return new Either3<int, CommonFraction, float>((CommonFraction)result);
                case 3: return new Either3<int, CommonFraction, float>((float)result);
                default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
```

So what I need to do? I really need this operator and I don't get how Either3 is not containing type. Maybe I have to some modifications in Either3 class?
C# version is 7.3

Comment: For those of us who haven't memorised all compiler errors by number, that's "One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type"

Comment: `Either3<T1, T2, T3>`, the open generic type, is not the same type as the constructed closed generic type `Either3<int, CommonFraction, float>`. So no, it's not the containing type.